# Unity transform.position always (0, 0, 0) for objects form obj import

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently been working with an imported obj file.

When imported into the editor all objects appear to be in the right position but have a position of (0, 0, 0).

Whenever I loop over the objects and write `transform.position` to a file each object is set as (0, 0, 0).

Just to check I used the parent object transformPosition which returned the same results.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: Just been asked. The problem is that they shouldn't be returning 0 for everything, they're all over the world.

```
rangeObjs = GameObject.Find("firing_range").GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
for(int i = 0; i < rangeObjs.Length; i++){
    Debug.Log(rangeObjs[i].transform.position.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Ok, great. What's your problem?

Comment: @Draco18s They shouldn't all be at 0, 0, 0. They're all at different locations.

Comment: @CBusBus can you show your codes?
and maybe some screenshot of how it's happening in the scene

Comment: @endrikexe I've added the code that's causing the issue. It works for other models without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it's seems that your model pivot is transformed into center of your root transform.

This is either your models has wrong pivot or this is bugs within unity that transform every pivot to the root (0,0,0)

Please, open your obj in other 3d modelling software like blender and see if the pivot is in zero position.

Please fix the pivot in 3d modelling software.

If it doesn't then you can try to export it to different format, e.g FBX (recomended) and try to import it back to unity.

But, if you want the tricky way.
You can make your MeshFilter GameObject to be the child of some parent that has the correct pivot position, you can make an Empty GameObject to make new pivot for this.

**EDIT**

Also check in the unity editor, Select your Child Object that has MeshFilter in it, and see the position of the object in the inspector.

Different Bound Location doesn't meant the pivot is in there, the mesh could be somewhere else, but it doesn't guarantee the pivot is in the same position of the mesh

Comment: Thanks for the response. The editor shows the same zero values, so I think you must be right about the pivot point. Is there a way I can resolve this without generating a new model?

Comment: _"But, if you want the tricky way. You can make your MeshFilter GameObject to be the child of some parent that has the correct pivot position, you can make an Empty GameObject to make new pivot for this."_

**STEP**
Right Click on your gameObject root, and select create Empty
then position it to the correct position corresponding to your MeshFilter, then make your Mesh Filter game object child of your new empty gameObject, drag and drop it to the empty gameObject.

Comment: and your loop code should be like this

'
rangeObjs = GameObject.Find("firing_range").transform;
foreach(Transform t in rangeObjs)
{
Debug.Log(t.position);
}

Comment: Sorry, I meant is there a way for me to figure their position from the existing pivot point?

Wasn't sure about the loop, I need to know what object they're attached to so I went with the mesh filter, would've just went with the game object but it was more convenient further down the line. Laziness  guess.

Comment: You can use Renderer.bounds to get the mesh center point, but this isn't the pivot, this just another way if you want to get the center of the mesh. The code above is modified version of your code because we don't use MeshFilter pivot anymore, because we use empty game object that don't have MeshFilter. here's a reference how you can get center of mesh https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I've tried using bounds centre but that point doesn't exist in my coordinates. As far as I know the insertion point should be one of the coordinates from the mesh but I'm not sure, at this point I was thrown off by the 0 point. The code's for an older version of Unity. I've tried bounds center but that doesn't appear in my coords either, I guess that's to be expected.

Comment: what do you mean? it doesn't exist?

Comment: It's a really simple model, I know all the points in it. Just checked the individual vertices and they're not what I was hoping for either.

Comment: what is your coordinates, and why using bounds doesn't exist?

, bounds is the property from MeshRenderer not MeshFilter

Comment: Sorry when I say doesn't exist I mean the centre point isn't in my list of points from the obj model.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking the **localPosition** of the objects? (as opposed to the object's positions)?

i.e. instead of;

```
foreach(Transform t in group){
  print(t.position)
}
```

use;

```
foreach(Transform t in group){
  print(t.localPosition)
}
```

Comment: I tried localPosition and TransformPoint from the parent. Neither returned different results.

Comment: hmmm... now that I can see your code, shouldn't you be checking the position of **transforms** of the the children of GameObject.Find("firing_range"). You seem to be checking the position of the MeshFilter component of each, not the actual child transforms themselves.

Comment: I've checked with the GameObject as well, that's just the last thing I checked. Sorry, should add, I've been checking position, localPosition and TransformPoint(position).